# Referenciar un archivo javascript en otro

Tags: javascript, html, objeto

Dispongo de un fichero html que contiene un boton, que al pulsarlo llama a una funcion "newBiblioteca()" que se encarga de crear un objeto de tipo Biblioteca. El problema es que al pulsar sobre el boton el navegador no hace nada. Y al ver la consola me dice que :

Uncaught ReferenceError: Biblioteca is not defined
    at newBiblioteca (functions.js:6)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index_biblioteca.html:22).

Me imagino que sea por que el fichero js que aloja la Biblioteca no esta referenciado desde la clase funciones que tengo que es la que llama el boton al ser pulsado.

El esquema de la pagina seria el siguiente: html->boton que llama a newBiblioteca -> DUDA-> clase biblioteca en fichero js

En duda me refiero con que, ¿Como puedo referenciar la clase que aloja el objeto biblioteca, dentro del fichero funciones que guarda la funcion de crear objetos de tipo biblioteca?

```js
function newBiblioteca() {
    var biblio= new Biblioteca() ;
    biblio.id=prompt("Teclea el identificador de la biblioteca");
    biblio.nombre=prompt("Teclea el nombre de la biblioteca");
    biblio.localidad=prompt("Teclea la localidad de la biblioteca");
    biblio.responsable=prompt("Teclea el nombre del responsable de la biblioteca");
    biblio.nLibros=prompt("Teclea el número de libros de la biblioteca");
    a[cont]=biblio;
    cont++;
    alert("Datos registrados con éxito");
}
```

```css
/* CONTENEDORES */
#f1{
    background-color: aqua;
    height: 65%;
    text-align : center;
}
#f2{
    background-color: bisque;
    height: 35%;
    text-align : center;
}

/* Columnas del div superior */
#f1c1{
    width: 33%;
    float: left;
}

#f1c2{
    width: 33%;
    margin:0 auto !important; 
    display:inline-block
}

#f1c3{
    width: 33%;
    float: right;
}

/* Columnas del div inferior */
#f2c1{
    width: 33%;
    float: left;
}

#f2c2{
    width: 33%;
    margin:0 auto !important; 
    display:inline-block
}

#f2c3{
    width: 33%;
    float: right;
}
```

```html
  <div id="f1">
            <div id="f1c1">
                <h5>BIBLIOTECA</h5>
            </div>
            <div id="f1c2">
                <h5>SOCIOS</h5>
            </div>
            <div id="f1c3">
                <h5>LIBRO</h5>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="f2">
            <div id="f2c1">
                <button onclick="newBiblioteca()">Nueva Biblioteca</button>
            </div>
            <div id="f2c2">
            </div>
            <div id="f2c3">
            </div>
        </div>
```

Al hacer var biblio = new Biblioteca(); No puedo crearlo correctamente ya que esta tratando de buscarlo dentro del mismo archivo cuando se encuentra en otro que seria el siguiente:

biblioteca.js:

```
var id=0, nLibros=0, cont=0;
var  nombre="", localidad="", responsable="";
var a = [];

function Biblioteca(id, nombre, localidad, responsable, nLibros){
    this.id=id;
    this.nombre=nombre;
    this.localidad=localidad;
    this.responsable=responsable;
    this.nLibros=nLibros;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pon tus archivos `javascript` dentro del `head` de tu página o al final del `body` de tu página, así:

Dentro del `head`:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="biblioteca.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="function.js"></script>
</head>
```

O al final del `body`:

```
<body>
    <!--    ...   -->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="biblioteca.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="function.js"></script>
</body>
```

Espero y te sirva, saludos.

Comment: gracias por la respuesta ;D

Answer (score 0):

No se trata de referenciar un js dentro de otro js. Si no de poner todas las referencias dentro del html. en ese momento el navegador "tragara" todo. La solucion seria asi:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/biblioteca.js"></script>
```

Poner esa linea dentro del meta de la pagina